Why is The Socket Unable To emit to my Frontend?
I have a Flask Route which needs to asynchronously send warnings to the front end and I am using SocketIO() for that purpose, here is what i did...
FLASK....
@app.route('/gotopagefullscreen', methods = ['POST'])
def gotopagefullscreen():
    """
     get required variables
    """

    try:
        page = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        #Send Warning To Socket
        socketio.emit('warning', 'Invalid Page Number', namespace='/')
        return redirect(f'fullscreen/{book_id}/{last_page}')


    total = book_row.iloc[0]['Total_Pages']

    if int(page) >= int(total):
         socketio.emit('warning', 'We are at the last Page', namespace='/')
         return redirect(f'fullscreen/{book_id}/{total-1}')

    if int(page) < 1:
         socketio.emit('warning', 'Invalid page number, We are at the first page.', namespace='/')
         return redirect(f'fullscreen/{book_id}/1')

    return redirect(f'fullscreen/{book_id}/{page}') 

JavaScript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event)=>{
            const socket = io();

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });

            socket.on('warning', function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        });

But I cant Get the alert. No Errors in the python terminal or the browser console.

I tried changing alert to console.log(), no use.
I tried to remove redirects reasoning, that it might be happening, but i just cant see it because it gets redirected, no use.
The Socket is connected, but not working in this particular case.

Here is a Reference to my project file. Please be kind and help me understand what I might be doing wrong. Thanks.

Your server has to identify what PORT it intends to listen on, and your client has to specifically identify the port it wants to connect to.  You're doing neither of those things.  Also, when you return a "redirect", the browser is going to load the new page without ever taking your action.

@TimRoberts Hello, Sorry, but It would be very helpful if you could direct me towards the correct implementation and/or resources. 1. The connect message seems to be working fine. 2. I will have to redirect eventually. Thanks again.

There's a lot of code you didn't show us, hence my confusion.    Do you see the "received my event" message from your Python server?

Stepping back, I'm not sure why you are using socketio for this at all.  It looks to me like you just want a normal request/reply model here.  Your gotopagefullscreen function should be returning a page that includes the error message, and the browser can display that with the warning.  As I said, as soon as the browser receives your redirect, it's going to flush the current page and load a new one.

Thanks @TimRoberts, that's what I have finally implemented, but the problem was that you can't really redirect to a dynamic variable with context in flask, or at least I couldn't find a way, otherwise I could have just passed the error message through the redirect. Anyway thanks.
